# How to use php require in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to add a PHP file to my CakePHP controller using the require "filename.php" but it's not working. here is the error message:

> require(filename.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

Comment: Check the path of the file!

Comment: Where did you put your file?

Comment: I placed in views/posts/posts.php

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `filename.php`? Is it an element? What version of Cakephp are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This means the file `filename.php` does not exist in the path from your script.

Do a `var_dump(getcwd())` to get path of your current working directory. If your file is not in this path, there is your problem.

You will most likely need to use a more specific path to the filename, such as

```
require(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'pathto' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'filename.php');
```

But probably you should be looking at [autoloading](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#manually-autoloading-plugin-classes) your file or use the [template functionality](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#view-templates) in CakePHP. In the absolute majority of cases, if you are including a file directly in a framework with `include` or `require`, there is reason to stop and rethink your solution. Chances are you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, if it's under `views/posts`, it's almost certain that it should be either a template or an element. @Easy, feel free to include some more details about what high-level problem you're trying to solve, and we can help point you in the right direction.